# How to install node modules for external evaluation?

Tags: external-language-cell, external-calls, javascript

I was hoping for some extra clarity configuring additional modules for use in external evaluation, since there's no mention of this in the [the nodejs workflow](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigureNodeJSForExternalEvaluate.html).

It seems mathematica looks only at `~/.node_modules`, *so is it sufficient to simply generate a soft link?*

```
cd ~; ln -s node_modules .node_modules
```

In decreasing importance, here are some specific sub-questions:

1. I prefer using yarn to manage required installations, do I have to use npm?
2. Do npm installs need to be global or user?
3. Does the fe or kernel need to be restarted; or evaluators re-registered after install or removal?

Knowing that any specific functionalities or modules will definitely not work (e.g. no browser ...) would help, and any pro-tips from Javascript developers would be appreciated. For example, would it be possible to add a `'package.json'` file for a notebook and isolate dependencies? I really don't want these mma configuration steps to interfere with my existing node-js work.

Comment: I guess most ppl here don’t use javascript?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. I use both JavaScript and Mathematica and find the question interesting. I have seen that many other questions have answers by people who work at Wolfram but they could never answer it if the question is closed. I vote to reopen.